# Visual Studio 2010 plugin to show current file EOL style

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, eol

It seems the EOL style in our current project isn't consistent. I'm looking for a Visual Studio plugin/extension to show the EOL style in the currently opened file as either LF, CRLF or Mixed.

Answer (score 0):

try to used the below codes

```
Dim TextLine As String
FileOpen(1, "TESTFILE", OpenMode.Input)   ' Open file.
Do While Not EOF(1)   ' Loop until end of file.
   TextLine = LineInput(1)   ' Read line into variable.
   Debug.WriteLine(TextLine)   ' Print to the Command window.
Loop
FileClose(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you looking for, but there is a build-in feature:

Tools -> Options

Environment -> Documents -> Check for consistent line endings on load

Comment: Thats what Im using right now, but its only checked when the file is opened and consantly closing and reopening files proved to cumbersome.